# validation with double value in Spring

Tags: java, spring, validation

I want to check score which have value: 0.00 <= value<= 10.00
I used:
 -Model(Score):

```
 @Range(min = (long) 0.0, max = (long) 10.0)
 private double score;
```

-messages.properties:

```
Range.score.score=Please input 0<= score <=10
```

-servlet-context.xml:

```
   <beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </beans:bean>
```

But the value = 10.01 has passed the check.
Please help me.

Comment: Of course. Casting `10.01` to `long` will truncate the value to `10`, making your check pass.

Comment: how can I validate the value only smaller than or equal 10?

Comment: Not with `@Range`, that's for sure.

Comment: sorry, I don't clear with your suggestion. If can't use @Range what should I use?

Comment: I think you are using `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Range`, but I'm not sure. If you are, I see in the [docs of the `Max` one level up](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html?is-external=true) the following: `"Note that double and float are not supported due to rounding errors (some providers might provide some approximative support)."`. The only one with decimals that is supported is `BigDecimal`, so perhaps use `@Range(min = new BigDecimal(0.0), max = new BigDecimal(10.0)) private BigDecimal score;`? For double I dunno..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I resolve my proplem with:

```
 @DecimalMax("10.0") @DecimalMin("0.0") 
 private double score;
```

Thank you lots @ Kayaman ,@hyness

Comment: The source code of `@DecimalMax` and `@DecimalMin` also says `Note that {@code double} and {@code float} are not supported due to rounding errors`...

Comment: It won't work. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.  First problem is you are trying to specify a data type in the attribute of the annotation.  You don't need to specify the data type or fraction either, this annotation only takes whole numbers.

Also, as specified by many others, doubles and floats are not allowed to rounding errors, so you need to use a BigDecimal instead of a double.  BigDecimal has a doubleValue() method to get the value as a double.

```
@Range(min = 0, max = 10)
private BigDecimal score;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of who just want to put constraint with a message

```
@DecimalMin(value = "1.0", message = "Please Enter a valid Deposit Amount")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = DoublePrecisionValidator.class)
public @interface DoublePrecision {
    String message() default "Invalid double precision";

    int precision() default 2;

    int maxDigits() default 10;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class DoublePrecisionValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DoublePrecision, Double> {
    private int precision;
    private int maxDigits;

    @Override
    public void initialize(DoublePrecision doublePrecision) {
        this.precision = doublePrecision.precision();
        this.maxDigits = doublePrecision.maxDigits();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Double value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true; // Null values are considered valid, add additional checks if needed
        }

        // Check precision
        double scaledValue = value * Math.pow(10, precision);
        long truncatedValue = (long) scaledValue;
        double restoredValue = truncatedValue / Math.pow(10, precision);

        // Check maxDigits
        String stringValue = Double.toString(value);
        int totalDigits = stringValue.length() - (stringValue.contains(".") ? 1 : 0);

        return value.equals(restoredValue) && totalDigits <= maxDigits;
    }
}
```