# Spring ConfigurationProperties validation of a Double value

Tags: spring-boot, configurationproperties

I have a property value that should range between 0 and 1.
I like Spring's `ConfigurationProperties` to validate the property value.

So in my `ConfigProperties` class I added the `@Validated` annotation and wrote this:

```
@Min(0)
@Max(1)
Double fraction;
```

The strange thing is that the validation works in a manner that looks like `flooring / roofing` the value from the property file.

This is the outcome of different values I put in the conf file:

`fraction=-2.1`  -> Spring reports an error and stops (good!)

`fraction=2.1`  -> Spring reports an error and stops (good!)

`fraction=-1.5` -> Spring doesn't report an error and starts (not good!)

`fraction=1.5` -> Spring doesn't report an error and starts (not good!)

I also tried using the `@Range` annotation, but with the same outcomes

Comment: `@Min` and `@Max` work for integers not doubles. Hence 1.5 gets converted to an int and will result in 1 instead of 2.... Even if 1.5 would be rounded to 2 it still would fail with values like 1.13 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is the solution [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460884/validation-with-double-value-in-spring):

```
   @DecimalMax("1.0") @DecimalMin("0.0")
    Double fraction;
```

Comment: Although that might work, according to the documentation `@DecimalMax` and `@DecimalMin` aren't supported on `double` either.

Answer (score 0):

As (clearly) stated by the documentation of both [`@Min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html) and [`@Max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html). The same applies to [`@DecimalMin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html) and [`@DecimalMax`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMax.html)

> Note that `double` and `float` are not supported due to rounding errors (some providers might provide some approximative support)

You can use a `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` instead.